# how to solve this NaN values (indexes) pandas problem when concatinating multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am trying to read and analyze multiple "covid-19 in KSA" CSV files, specifically 52, using pandas, and plot them, then inserting these plots into a folium map.
I am using python 3.9.1 on windows 10. IDE is jupyter notebook for testing and then will write the final code in pycharm.
basically, each region of the 13 regions in KSA has 4 files: cases, recoveries, deaths, active. (delimiter=;)
sample:

```
    Daily / Cumulative  Indicator   Date    Event   City    Region  Cases (person)
0   Cumulative  Active  2020-08-04  NaN Shuwaq  Tabuk   5
1   Cumulative  Active  2020-08-05  NaN Tabuk   Tabuk   243
2   Cumulative  Active  2020-08-05  NaN Al Badʻ Tabuk   1
3   Cumulative  Active  2020-08-06  NaN Tabuk   Tabuk   229
4   Cumulative  Active  2020-08-06  NaN Taymaʼ  Tabuk   5
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2220    Cumulative  Active  2020-12-22  NaN Al Wajh Tabuk   2
2221    Cumulative  Active  2020-12-26  NaN Al Wajh Tabuk   2
2222    Cumulative  Active  2021-01-01  NaN Al Wajh Tabuk   2
2223    Cumulative  Active  2021-01-02  NaN Al Wajh Tabuk   2
2224    Cumulative  Active  2020-12-06  NaN Abu Rakah   Tabuk   1
```

I cleaned unwanted columns, renamed similar columns for the concatenation:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file1 = pd.read_csv("data/tabuk_total_active.csv", delimiter=";", parse_dates=True, index_col="Date")
file2 = pd.read_csv("data/tabuk_daily_cases.csv", delimiter=";", parse_dates=True, index_col="Date")
file3 = pd.read_csv("data/tabuk_daily_deaths.csv", delimiter=";", parse_dates=True, index_col="Date")
file4 = pd.read_csv("data/tabuk_daily_recovories.csv", delimiter=";", parse_date=True, index_col="Date")
data1 = file1.drop(["Event", "Daily / Cumulative", "City", "Indicator"], axis=1)
data2 = file2.drop(["Event", "Daily / Cumulative", "City", "Indicator"], axis=1)
data3 = file3.drop(["Event", "Daily / Cumulative", "City", "Indicator"], axis=1)
data4 = file4.drop(["Event", "Daily / Cumulative", "City", "Indicator"], axis=1)
df1 = data1.rename(columns={'Cases (person)': 'active'})
df2 = data2.rename(columns={'Cases (person)': 'cases'})
df3 = data3.rename(columns={'Cases (person)': 'deaths'})
df4 = data4.rename(columns={'Cases (person)': 'recovories'})
```

result:

```
 df1
        Region  active
    Date        
    2020-08-04  Tabuk   5
    2020-08-05  Tabuk   243
    2020-08-05  Tabuk   1
    2020-08-06  Tabuk   229
    2020-08-06  Tabuk   5
    ... ... ...
    2020-12-22  Tabuk   2
    2020-12-26  Tabuk   2
    2021-01-01  Tabuk   2
    2021-01-02  Tabuk   2
    2020-12-06  Tabuk   1

df2

    Region  cases
Date        
2020-03-20  Tabuk   1
2020-03-28  Tabuk   3
2020-03-29  Tabuk   1
2020-03-30  Tabuk   1
2020-04-01  Tabuk   2
... ... ...
2021-02-03  Tabuk   1
2021-02-03  Tabuk   1
2021-02-04  Tabuk   1
2021-02-04  Tabuk   1
2021-02-05  Tabuk   1

df3

    Region  deaths
Date        
2020-04-16  Tabuk   1
2020-05-31  Tabuk   2
2020-06-02  Tabuk   2
2020-06-06  Tabuk   1
2020-06-07  Tabuk   1
2020-06-09  Tabuk   1
2020-06-11  Tabuk   1
2020-06-13  Tabuk   1
2020-06-14  Tabuk   2
2020-06-15  Tabuk   1
2020-06-21  Tabuk   1
2020-06-26  Tabuk   1
2020-06-28  Tabuk   2
2020-07-01  Tabuk   1
2020-07-04  Tabuk   3
2020-07-05  Tabuk   4
2020-07-07  Tabuk   2
2020-07-08  Tabuk   1
2020-07-11  Tabuk   3
2020-07-12  Tabuk   1
2020-07-14  Tabuk   3
2020-07-15  Tabuk   3
2020-07-16  Tabuk   1
2020-07-17  Tabuk   2
2020-07-23  Tabuk   2
2020-07-24  Tabuk   3
2020-08-02  Tabuk   1
2020-08-03  Tabuk   2
2020-08-10  Tabuk   3
2020-08-11  Tabuk   2
2020-08-16  Tabuk   1
2020-08-20  Tabuk   1
2020-08-21  Tabuk   1
2020-08-22  Tabuk   1
2020-08-23  Tabuk   1
2020-09-05  Tabuk   1
2020-09-08  Tabuk   2
2020-09-09  Tabuk   1
2020-09-11  Tabuk   1
2020-09-14  Tabuk   1
2020-09-15  Tabuk   1
2020-09-19  Tabuk   1
2020-09-25  Tabuk   1
2020-09-29  Tabuk   1
2020-10-02  Tabuk   2
2020-10-06  Tabuk   1
2020-10-07  Tabuk   1
2020-10-11  Tabuk   1
2020-10-12  Tabuk   1
2020-10-27  Tabuk   1
2020-10-29  Tabuk   1
2020-10-30  Tabuk   1
2020-11-15  Tabuk   1
2020-11-25  Tabuk   1
2020-12-04  Tabuk   1
2020-12-08  Tabuk   1
2020-12-12  Tabuk   1
2021-01-02  Tabuk   1
2021-01-11  Tabuk   1
2021-01-14  Tabuk   1

df4
    Region  recovories
Date        
2020-04-07  Tabuk   4
2020-04-12  Tabuk   1
2020-04-13  Tabuk   1
2020-04-18  Tabuk   2
2020-04-19  Tabuk   1
... ... ...
2021-02-03  Tabuk   1
2021-02-04  Tabuk   2
2021-02-04  Tabuk   1
2021-02-05  Tabuk   1
2021-02-05  Tabuk   1
```

sorted messy dates:

```
df1 = df1.sort_values(by="Date")
df2 = df2.sort_values(by="Date")
df3 = df3.sort_values(by="Date")
df4 = df4.sort_values(by="Date")
```

next I wanted to merge the dataframes in order to plot them easily in one plot:

```
tabuk_all= [df1, df2, df3, df4]
all = pd.concat(tabuk_all)
all.head()



    Region  active  cases   deaths  recovories
Date                    
2020-03-20  Tabuk   1.0 NaN NaN NaN
2020-03-21  Tabuk   1.0 NaN NaN NaN
2020-03-22  Tabuk   1.0 NaN NaN NaN
2020-03-23  Tabuk   1.0 NaN NaN NaN
2020-03-24  Tabuk   1.0 NaN NaN NaN
```

and these NaN values appeared.I think the reason is the dates that don't align.
how can I first merge rows with the same month for each file so it would look like this :

```
   Region  active                   >>>  Date  active
    Date                                   march-2020   400
    2020-08-04  Tabuk   5                  April-2020   350
    2020-08-05  Tabuk   243                may-2020   670
    2020-08-05  Tabuk   1                  ...
    2020-08-06  Tabuk   229
    2020-08-06  Tabuk   5                  ...
    ... ... ...
    2020-12-22  Tabuk   2
    2020-12-26  Tabuk   2
    2021-01-01  Tabuk   2
    2021-01-02  Tabuk   2
    2020-12-06  Tabuk   1
```

and then merge each region's 4 files so it looks like this :

```
    Date    active  cases   deaths  recovories
0   march-2020  34  234  22  1232
1   april-2020  55  345  23  1234
2   may-2020    100 367  5   234
```

what would be the most efficient way to read and do this for all the files without going for each file?

Comment: I am confused by your statement " I had to drop the index_col parameter."  Do you mean you dropped the index?  Why not use the date as the index and then you can join the the df2.cases, df3.deaths, and df4.recoveries into df1

Comment: oh sorry @itprorh66 I must have been confused I remember it threw an error saying no such index. however, when I ran the code again the error disappeared.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data contained in df2 and df3 after you have them cleaned of messy data, similar to your sample of df1?

Comment: yes... i edited the post.

Comment: So what is wrong with the concatenated df named all?  It shows NaNs for the column/rows where you don't have any reported values.  You can replace the NaNs with 0 and then groupby the df[date]..month_name()

Comment: the problem is that there are reported values in all files on a lot of dates yet it shows NaN values in all columns except the active cases column for example: here in this all df row : (2020-03-30 Tabuk 6.0 NaN NaN NaN) the date is March 30. the same date on cases df(df2) :(2020-03-30 Tabuk 1) as u can see there is a number on the active column, but there is a NaN value in the cases column, although it should be 1. @itprorh66

Comment: besides I wanna know what is the best way to do the following: opening the 4 files for each region(total of 52), cleaning them, merging dates for each month for each file so I would only have 12 rows(12 months from march 2020 to Feb 2021) for each file, and then merging each region's 4 files so I would have final 13 DFs for each region with the columns (date, cases, active, deaths, recoveries) and the 12 rows at once without having to go through every on of them (if possible).